# Add A list Items to Combobox using Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I want to add a List to ComboBox through Dispatcher.BeginInvoke. But when I try to put it in a loop, only last value is loading.

```
    private void LoadToComboBox(List<string> msg)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < msg.Count; i++)
        {
           this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => cmbListItems.Items.Add(msg[i]));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() is an asynchronous call. What is happening is that by the time you are calling your  `cmbListItems.Items.Add()` function, it is already set to `msg.Count`.

Try something like this:

```
private void LoadToComboBox(List<string> msg)
        {

            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => 
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < msg.Count; i++) {
                    cmbListItems.Items.Add(msg[i]);
                }
            });

        }
```